# Daemon not running when started over ssh

Tags: linux, random

I'm trying to start the rngd daemon by remotely starting it via ssh. Unfortunately it does not seem to run until I log onto the machine. The command I'm using is:

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ... user@host "sudo rngd \
       -r /dev/urandom -o /dev/random -t 10"`
```

When I call `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` I get low (150ish) values which makes me think that rngd is not running. However if I log onto the box, wait a few seconds and check, the pool is full (3000s).

Comment: ssh may need to provide a tty via the `-t` option (I'm not sure if rngd requires one or not)

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving us a large amount of information to go on (for instance, under what operating system?), but my thought is that you shouldn't be doing this one.

Assuming that you're using Linux, `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` [are linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random). `/dev/random` only gives out random bits when it has them, and `/dev/urandom` takes that same pool of random bits, but keeps extending the `/dev/random` bits indefinitely.

Your command just feeds back those extended pseudo-random bits from `/dev/random` into `/dev/random`.

Answer (score -1):

My mistake was using " instead of '. As far as I understand using "" causes the shell to interpret the string when running the ssh command on the local machine. I'm not sure what was being passed to the remote machines, possible the result of the command. '' will cause the shell to pass the string unaltered.

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ... user@host 'sudo rngd \
       -r /dev/urandom -o /dev/random -t 10'
```

works. I decided to go another way however and us `haveged`:

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ... user@host 'sudo apt-get \
        install haveged'
```

Is all that needs to be done. It will install `haveged`, start it and add an entry to cause it to start on boot.

Comment: That can't be right. With the command here, `"` and `'` produce exactly the same effect. The difference is that between double quotes, variable and command substitutions are expanded (`$var`, `$(cmd)`) and some backslashes quote the next character, but there are none of these here.